# How to avoid weird text breaks in MS word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have MS word document when change it's orientation to portrait some text get break in to vertical lines.I can't find any paragraph marks to delete and fix it.

[image]

How to avoid this text break?

Comment: please show the Word screenshot in normal mode including the ruler

Answer (score 1):

This is a right tab.  Turn on the ruler (ribbon: View).

[Using the ruler](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-the-ruler-in-word-775014ca-7bb9-4b75ba19-4478c4a836d1)

[image: Right tab example]